# AppCache not caching files on Chrome 34 for Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, html5-appcache

I have an app that will cache itself using appcache, which works fine on desktop and I can see the appcache status in the console and chrome://appcache-internals. However, on mobile it doesn't download the files at all and chrome://appcache-internals doesn't even show an entry.

manifest.appcache is as follows:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2014-04-11:v4

index.php
favicon.ico
css/main.css
img/bg.png
img/logo.png
js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js
js/main.js
js/bigtext.js

NETWORK:
*
```

Nothing fancy at all, just completely baffling! Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache wasn't being served with the correct mime type. Adding the following line to `.htaccess` resolves the issue:

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```